# Multiple files and one handler for lambda functions in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I have the following folder structure

```
src
  -- functions
     -- Test
        -- __init__.py
        -- app.py
        -- create_data.py
-- template.yaml
```

Inside the `app.py` I have that:

```
from .create_data import create_data
....
def handler(event, context):
   return create_data(item=event)
...
```

In my template.yaml I have:

```
  TestFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/functions/Test
      Handler: app.handler
....
```

So, my idea is to have an `app.py` that handles the request and uses another `.py` (in that case, `create_data.py`) to manipulate the request and save into the database
But, when I try to run the function (locally or on API Gateway) I receive the error:

`{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Unable to import module 'app': attempted relative import with no known parent package"}`

If I remove the importing of `create_data` it works.

How do I fix that? I mean, I don't want to always put ALL my code in `app.py`, I would like to split into files

Comment: I hope you find this thread helpful, https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1963#issuecomment-624425404